# Jupyter Plotting just the graph without the execution commands

Tags: python, jupyter

Hi I am using jupyter notebook and every time I plot I am getting all the matplolib inline executions as per below. The graph appears at the bottom. But I would like to get only the graph as I would like to use it for presenting.
[image]

I tried the below

```
    %matplotlib inline
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

but it doesn't work always
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working on python 3?

If yes add

```
%matplotlib notebook
```